# Winform Invalid Handle Error when calling function from WIn32.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, handle, user32

I am building a Winform application that requires Clipboard fonctions hence I need to make calls to user32.dll . Now, whenevr I launched the application, I got the following error `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'`.

After further investigation, it turns out that when I attempt to register the clipBoardViewer using `SetClipboardViewer()`, I get an `invalid Handle` error code from user32.dll .

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace NiceClip
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        protected static extern int SetClipboardViewer(int hWndNewViewer);
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        protected static extern int GetLastError();
        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove, IntPtr hWndNewNext);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        IntPtr nextClipboardViewer;
        NotifyIcon niceClipIcon;
        Icon niceClipIconImage;
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        bool reallyQuit = false;
        bool isCopying = false;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            nextClipboardViewer = (IntPtr)SetClipboardViewer((int)this.Handle);

            if (this.clipboardHistoryList.Items.Count > 0)
                this.clipboardHistoryList.SetSelected(0, true);
            clipboardHistoryList.Select();

            this.TopMost = true;

            niceClipIconImage = Properties.Resources.clipboard;
            niceClipIcon = new NotifyIcon
            {
                Icon = niceClipIconImage,
                Visible = true
            };

            MenuItem quitMenuItem = new MenuItem("Quit");
            MenuItem showFormItem = new MenuItem("NiceClip");
            this.contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(showFormItem);
            this.contextMenu.MenuItems.Add("-");
            this.contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(quitMenuItem);

            niceClipIcon.ContextMenu = contextMenu;

            quitMenuItem.Click += QuitMenuItem_Click;
            showFormItem.Click += ShowForm;
        }

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes care of the external DLL calls to user32 to receive notification when
        /// the clipboard is modified. Passes along notifications to any other process that
        /// is subscribed to the event notification chain.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
        {
            const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
            const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // Error is code 1400 (invalid window handle)

            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                    if (!isCopying)
                        AddClipBoardEntry();
                    break;
                case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                    if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
                        nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
                    else
                        SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam,
                                    m.LParam);
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a clipboard history to the clipboard history list.
        /// </summary>
        private void AddClipBoardEntry()
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsText()) // FAILS HERE
            {
                string clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(clipboardText))
                {
                    clipboardHistoryList.Items.Insert(0, clipboardText);
                    toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Entry added in the clipboard history.";
                    deleteButton.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "History entry was not added because it was null or empty";
            }
        }
```

THe line `int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();` returns error code 1400 which is **Invalid window handle**, [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385(v=vs.85).aspx).

### Possible Solutions

I have verified that the thread apartment is correctly set

```
namespace NiceClip
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]        // Here
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to use `GC.KeepAlive()` so it wouldn't collect the form or it's handle but I really don't understand why it would.

When I debug the application, I observe that, RIGHT BEFORE calling `SetClipBoardViewer()`, the form handle has a value (that I think) is valid, at least it's not `null` or `0x0000`so I don't understand why the handle would be deemed as invalid.

### Note

- The application has compiled before on the same computer, I just
  haven't worked on it for a while and now it doesn't work.
- The full application is available [on GitHub at this commit](https://github.com/Gaboik/NiceClip/commit/626adef96d6bf3540d7072f613d80fb09fe5039b) in it's current state (minus a few lines I added for debugging purposes and some comments to help you guys make sense out of this).

Comment: Couldn't reproduce error on my machine. May be your security configuration has been modified. P.S: I'm running windows 10.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 too with VS2017. I remember seeing a popup about a debugging security setting which I kind of ignored (I probably shouldn't have). Can you tell me more about it?

Comment: This link might help you understand why you are having that warning dialog: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-enable-clickonce-security-settings

Comment: I tried setting the application as "full trust" without much success. I then disabled the Clicked Once security but it didn't do anything either.

Comment: I tried the application from GIT with Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 7. I can not even run the application, not even when I start Visual Studio as administrator. I always get **SecurityException was unhandled** in **mscrorlib.dll** *(without any application code)*. This will probably need a more work to debug. I try to do something with it at a later time *(at least I hope I will be able)*...

Comment: @Julo Yes it seems you get the same error as I get.

Comment: @DipenShah So I uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2017, just to be sure, and the problem still occurs. Furthermore, here's the popup I was talking about https://imgur.com/mzdHQjG

Comment: After commenting out `nextClipboardViewer` *(line 28)*, `niceClipIcon` *(lines 36-40, 48, 236)* and removing `WndProc` *(`#if false` on line 58 amd `#endif` on line 108)* the application starts, but with a interesting message from the main window *(__Microsoft .NET Security Warning__: Never enter personal information or password into a window unless you can verify and trust the source of the request)* and the application do not end after the window is closed. The issue I see here are too many initialisations in constructor and no check for finished initialisations in `WndProc`.

Comment: Using GetLastError() or Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() correctly is very, very important.  The code does not, the crucial detail is that it can only produce a valid code *right after* a winapi call failed.  So it can correctly retrieve the "last error".  If you call it at any other time then a random number is to be expected.  Unfortunately often 0, so it seems to be okay, but not always.  You must delete that code.  Another flaw in that code is using the Handle property in the constructor, far too early, and assuming it never changes.  The pinvoke call belongs in OnHandleCreated().

Comment: And the pinvoke declarations are quite wrong, get better ones from the pinvoke.net web site.

Comment: There is one more thing you can try. Download a clean copy from GIT *(or delete all Visual Studio files (directory `.vs` for VS2015+) and all compiled folders)* and try to compile it. I had a similar problem *(but for C++)* in Visual Studio 2015 Express; some settings caused problems loading the project and clearing the `*.suo` file was necessary step to open the project.

Comment: The last possible thing I see, that can cause this problem is the line `nextClipboardViewer = (IntPtr)SetClipboardViewer((int)this.Handle);` Try to move it from constructor to `protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)`

Comment: And one more thing. Invalid handle can be caused by altering number on x64 systems caused by incorrect PInvokde definition; [see this link for correct PInvoke definition](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetClipboardViewer.html)

Comment: Note that I just had the chance to test the code on another computer and it compiled without a prolem and works like a charm so at this point I'm pretty lost. I will certainly try all you guys' suggestions when I have a little bit more time!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error *([source code from GIT](https://github.com/Gaboik/NiceClip))*. Change the application setting.

Go to `Properties` --> `Security` and change to 'This is a Full trust application'.

After this change the application starts without a problem and the clipboard functions work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I had already tried that but it didn't change anything

Comment: @Gaboik1 This worked fine for me. Try to disable the option.

Comment: I disabled the ClickOnce security option altogether and it doesn't work for me at least.